# change colors with function parameters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I am trying to change colors using a function and its parameters with template string, can't figure out the correct way of doing it. Can somebody help?

```
function colorize(choice,color){
    choice.style.transition = 'all 450ms'
    choice.style.borderColor = `"${color}"`
    setTimeout(()=> choice.style.borderColor = 'rgba(60, 70, 127, 0.2)','700')
}
colorize(userDomChoice,green)
```

Comment: Did you mean `"green"`?

Comment: Thanks a lot Konrad now it works with "green" instead of green inside the function, but is there also a way to use template string?

Comment: You shouldn't put explicit quotes around the `borderColor` style.

Comment: Just use `.borderColor = color;`

Comment: thanks a lot Barmar, that is correct but also need to have the quotes on "green" to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need a template string for setting the border color

```
choice.style.borderColor = color;
```

Then add quotes around `green` in the `colorize` call

```
colorize(userDomChoice,'green');
```

Edit: Just as a note, you don't need the time in setTimeout to be in quotes

```
setTimeout(() => choice.style.borderColor = 'rgba(60, 70, 127, 0.2)',700);
```